# Defining aliases in a statistical query

Tags: mysql, aliases

I need to do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM some_table
 WHERE someAlias1 = someValue1 
   AND someAlias2 = someValue2;
```

`someAlias` is an alias for a column in `some_table`. In my case I can't name the columns directly; I need to use aliases.

The issue is that I only know about defining aliases inside the select clause which I don't see how I can do in this case.

Is there a way to accomplish what I need in this case?

edit: Why do I need aliases? I'm building a query from alternative parts, and the condition above applies to different columns from different tables, but with the same logical role. So I need a way to relate to different alternative columns with the same name.

I will appreciate if you answer this question only if you know an answer, even if you don't understand why may I need an alias

Comment: Just curious, why can't you name the columns directly?

Comment: Why do you need to use aliases? How did you arrive at this restriction when you _can't_ even use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a nested SELECT statement then draw the count out from the inner query, I don't really see a way to escape using the column names

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM(
        SELECT col1 as someAlias1, 
               col2 as someAlias2
        FROM   some_table
        WHERE  someAlias1 = someValue1
        AND    someAlias2 = someValue2
       ) as inner
```

Comment: +1 for inner query which associates directly to the question. Also, included a second query where conditions are use in the outer query with the help of an Alias

Answer (score 2):

I can't figure out a scenario where you can't name the columns directly. If the column name is duplicated, prepend the table name:

```
WHERE someTable1.someColumn1 = someValue1
```

If the column name is a reserved keyword or contains spaces, quote it:

```
WHERE `some Column1` = someValue1
```

You can even combine both:

```
WHERE someTable1.`some Column1` = someValue1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use aliases? The only reason to use aliases in your query would be for re-use in e.g. an "having" clause, like:

```
select count(*)  as C 
  from some_table 
 where someAlias1=someValue1 
   and someAlias2=someValue2
having C > someLimit1;
```